# What design pattern would apply when I need to retrieve data from both MySQL DB and local XML files?

Tags: php, xml, database, design-patterns, doctrine-orm

I am currently using Doctrine 2 to handle the ORM with the mysql db, but if I also wanted to store the same data in an XML format, and be able to retrieve from both data sources, what would be the best way to do this?  Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 1):

The [Abstract Factory pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern)

- Define an Interface that includes all the operations you need to perform.
- Create two concrete classes that both implement that interface, but implement the interface methods differently.
- Create a factory method with a signature of returning the interface you defined, and can return instances of either concrete type based on a parameter.
- Program to the only to the interface (and not the concrete classes).